# Delete the particular user without using admin panel in django

Tags: django

I have created my models using django user model. I am able to perform the edit functionality to the created form.Now i want to do DELETE the particular user details by using DELETE button.Here is my code

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

forms.py

```
class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name','last_name','username','email','password']
        help_texts={
            'username': None
        }
```

views.py

```
 def delete_profile(request, id):
    profile = UserProfileInfo.objects.filter(id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('signupapp:index'))
    return render(request, "signupapp/delete_profile.html", {'profile': profile})
```

delete_profile.html

```
    <form action="" method ="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p>Are you sure to delete "{{UserProfileInfo.username}}"?</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Delete"/>
</form>
```

Delete button link

index.html

```
<a href="{% url 'signupapp:delete' request.user.id %}"><input type="button" value="Delete"/></a><br>
```

When i run this code it is working.But the user I am deleting is not deleting in the database.

Can anyone help me to clear it.
Thanks in advance..

Comment: can you share your models?

Comment: yeah I added my models.Please check it once

Answer (score 1):

You are using auth user id to delete user profile id

try this

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
def delete_profile(request, id):  --> id : is auth user id
    user = User.objects.get(id=id)
    profile = UserProfileInfo.objects.filter(user=user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        profile.delete()
        User.objects.filter(id=id).delete()
```

Comment: It is showing an error like this  NameError at /delete/2/
name 'User' is not defined

Comment: you need to import user

Comment: It,s working but the user with that id is not deleting in the database